# Selectable but not editable html text field

Tags: html, input

I am working on a mobile website and I have a text input field.

I want it to be selected and copiable but not editable. When I add `readonly` or `onfocus="this.blur()"` it becomes unselectable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check this out.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">
    example text
</textarea>
```

**Edit:**

You can reassign text input value everytime it changes by adding input listener.

```
var inp = $("input")[0]; // select the input with proper selector
var default_value = inp.value;

inp.addEventListener("input", function () { 
    this.value = default_value;
}, false);
```

Working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfr9p/1/).

Comment: Ok. this selects but does not display the copy and paste dialog no matter what I do.

Comment: How about now? Is this ok?