# Readonly Text input field in Phonegap are editable

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, webkit

I have an input field with text value. I want this data to be read-only. The input is used in a Phonegap / Cordova 3.0 mobile app. Even with `readonly='readonly'` attribute, when I click the input field it brings the keyboard and I am able to edit the text on both iOS and Android.

I have chosen an input field because I want the user to be able to copy and paste this text if he wishes to by using the native copy-paste functionality of the device.

Is there an option to still use input text field that is readonly on webkit when using Phonegap apps?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479423/selectable-but-not-editable-html-text-field) and it didn't work either. Also worth mentioning that the input field HTML code is inserted dynamically using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it readonly by jquery

```
<textarea cols="20" id="txtWhowasinterOther" name="txtWhowasinterOther" rows="2"></textarea>

$('#txtWhowasinterOther').attr("readonly", true).css({ "background-color": "grey" });
```

**Here is the demo**  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7MBzm/)

Comment: Editable as in what? In this demo you cannot enter any value.

Comment: double check it and it worked. Sorry for the mistake